# Change PostgreSQL collation to UTF8

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

I use PostgeqSQL 10 on a win10 laptop. The Encoding is OK, it is UTF8, but I want to create a new database that has Collation and Character Type of UTF8.

I cannot choose the Collation I want from the pgAdmin GUI. So I open the SQL shell and try to enforce it like

```
CREATE DATABASE cml
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf8'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

but this does not work either. I get `ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_US.utf8"`.
I dont want en_US after all, because my database will be in Greek.

So, how do I enforce the Collation and Character Type I want?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Greek` to specify the Greek collation and character type on Windows.

Comment: Hi Laurenz. So, just put    `LC_COLLATE = 'Greek'    LC_CTYPE = 'Greek'` 
 and that will count as UTF8? What about setting the UTF8 and not depend on a specific language, just like mySQL sets `utf8_general_ci`  . Thanks

Comment: In addition to specifying `LC_COLLATE = 'Greek' LC_CTYPE = 'Greek'` you should also use `ENCODING = UTF8`.